# I want to put text in an input field by pressing a button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input-field

I have a button called suggestion that the script is attached. I have an input field for the user to input their name. If they click the button I want a to populate the input field with a random suggestion. I know how to do the random part, but can not find an example of how to put that string into the input field where they could edit it or except it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class RandomChar : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text ourName;
    public string rndName = "bob";
    public void SetText(string textOurName)
    {
        textOurName = rndName;
        ourName.text = textOurName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is an actual `InputField` then you should not go through the `Text` component but rather directly through the [`InputField.text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField.html)

```
public InputField ourName;

public void SetText()
{
    ourName.text = GetRandomName ();
}
```